# doxygen relative image paths and source directory structure

Tags: git, version-control, doxygen

I use doxygen for documentation, and I have my sources under git. 
I want paths in my documentation to be relative to the project dir, as I check it out in different places.

As the html subdir is generated by doxygen, it is not under version control.

However, it seems if I want to use relative paths for images, I need to put the images somewhere under the html directory - I played with using "../images" as IMAGE_PATH, that does not work.

My images should be under version control.

Is there a good way to organize my sources to make this work?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In principle doxygen should copy images from their original place to the HTML directory. Can you give an example (code) how you address the image?